# Angular Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'abc', required by directive 'def', can't be found

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've followed a tutorial and read from the documentation but don't understand what i'm doing wrong. I always get .Here's what i have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="directives/communicate.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

        app.controller('abc', function($scope) {

        });

        app.directive('abd', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'AE',
                controller: function($scope) {
                    $scope.tab = [];
                    console.log('hello')

                    this.tab = function() {
                        $scope.tab.push('test');
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        app.directive('def', function() {
            return {
                require: 'abc',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs, abcCtrl) {
                    console.log(abcCtrl.tab);
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    {{ 1 + 1 }}
    <div def abc></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the end i always get Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'abc', required by directive 'def', can't be found. How come ?

Answer (score -2):

Got it! It was a typo :(

```
app.directive('abd', function() {
...
```

should be

```
app.directive('abc', function() {
...
```